# Jetpack Compose theme not displaying on emulator

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a theme and I've applied it to my activity but when I run the app on the emulator, I do not see it with the colours specified in the theme (it should be some purple but I'm just seeing cyan coloured buttons). Is this an emulator issue or is it something to do with how I've applied the theme? This is what I see:

[image]

Color.kt

```
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color

val Purple80 = Color(0xFFD0BCFF)
val PurpleGrey80 = Color(0xFFCCC2DC)
val Pink80 = Color(0xFFEFB8C8)

val Purple40 = Color(0xFF6650a4)
val PurpleGrey40 = Color(0xFF625b71)
val Pink40 = Color(0xFF7D5260)
```

Theme.kt

```
private val DarkColorScheme = darkColorScheme(
    primary = Purple80,
    secondary = PurpleGrey80,
    tertiary = Pink80
)

private val LightColorScheme = lightColorScheme(
    primary = Purple40,
    secondary = PurpleGrey40,
    tertiary = Pink40

    /* Other default colors to override
    background = Color(0xFFFFFBFE),
    surface = Color(0xFFFFFBFE),
    onPrimary = Color.White,
    onSecondary = Color.White,
    onTertiary = Color.White,
    onBackground = Color(0xFF1C1B1F),
    onSurface = Color(0xFF1C1B1F),
    */
)

@Composable
fun MorseComposeAppTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    // Dynamic color is available on Android 12+
    dynamicColor: Boolean = true,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val colorScheme = when {
        dynamicColor && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S -> {
            val context = LocalContext.current
            if (darkTheme) dynamicDarkColorScheme(context) else dynamicLightColorScheme(context)
        }

        darkTheme -> DarkColorScheme
        else -> LightColorScheme
    }
    val view = LocalView.current
    if (!view.isInEditMode) {
        SideEffect {
            val window = (view.context as Activity).window
            window.statusBarColor = colorScheme.primary.toArgb()
            WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, view).isAppearanceLightStatusBars = darkTheme
        }
    }

    MaterialTheme(
        colorScheme = colorScheme,
        typography = Typography,
        content = content
    )
}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
    @SuppressLint("UnusedMaterial3ScaffoldPaddingParameter")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val toner = ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, ToneGenerator.MAX_VOLUME)
        val dotTime = 200
        val dashTime = 3 * dotTime

        setContent {
            MorseComposeAppTheme {
                Scaffold(
                    topBar = { TopAppBar(title = { Text("Morse Code") }) }
                ) {
                    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight()) {

                        Box(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .weight(2f)
                                .padding(all = 2.dp)
                        ) {
                            SoundButton(label = "Dot") {
                                toner.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_SUP_DIAL, dotTime)
                            }
                        }


                        Box(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .weight(1f)
                                .padding(all = 2.dp)
                        ) {
                            SoundButton(label = "Dash") {
                                toner.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_SUP_DIAL, dashTime)

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
          



        }
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun SoundButtonPreview() {
    MorseComposeAppTheme {
        SoundButton("Text") {}
    }
}


@Composable
fun SoundButton(label: String, onClick: () -> Unit) {
    Button(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        onClick = onClick,
    ) {
        Text(
            text = label,
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In "Material Me" (Android 12+) the colors of your application will be replaced by colors which user selected. (so-called dynamic color)

if you don't want to use dynamic color inside your application you can use `dynamicColor = false` in your code like below.

```kotlin
MorseComposeAppTheme(dynamicColor = false) {
   // scaffold
}
```

Comment: Perfect that worked, thank you so much

Comment: @Amanda_C you're welcome if the answer is acceptable, please mark it as accepted